# UDP socket recv functionality

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

If I have incoming data at the client's end and my code looks something like this:

```
while True:
   message, address = self.sock.recvfrom(4096)
   ...........................................
   ...........................................
   ...........................................
```

^ and based on what I receive every time, I perform different operations here some of which can be long string operations in this loop.
My question is that meanwhile these operations are being performed, if I receive data from the server on this client socket, will the data be dropped since the client wont be listening until I complete the operations and go back to the start of the loop
Thanks

Comment: You are correct. The application will not be looking for input from your socket until it arrives back at that line of code. You may want to look into concurrency (multi-threading) to achieve a more responsive application.

Answer (score 2):

If by 'listening' you mean actually getting data with the `recvfrom`, then no, there are buffers inside the kernel that handle that kind of stuff and send data to recvfrom function once you call it back to receive more. If you don't call recvfrom for a long time though, that buffer might fill up upon getting new data, and will start dropping old datagrams to make space for newer ones: the frequency for this to happen depends on the size of that buffer. Your bigger problem in using UDP would be unreliability, since UDP can and will drop datagrams depending on various factors.

Comment: Thank you so much. Well the purpose of the assignment is to implement reliability on UDP sockets!

Comment: Good luck with that then! If you found my answer useful you could mark it as default answer and/or upvote it, and just as a side note, tagging each datagram with an incremental value could help in detecting which datagrams were dropped, and ask the server to resend them, if that is your assignment. Thanks!

Comment: @Faizan: UDP can be used reliably... provided you use a higher level protocol above it that will care of packet loss. A common way is to use some *meta data* (in fact a higher level header) containing the packet number and implementing a resend packet feature.

Comment: @Nastor: We do not call it the *default* answer but the *accepted* one...

Comment: @SergeBallesta That is a really important thing to point out in a question asking for UDP protocol usage. Thanks, I will try to correct my dictionary.

Comment: @Nastor: I did not want to be offensive. But as Faizan is a new user here, I just prefered him to learn the common site wordings. You can of course call that the way you want :-). And I have upvoted your answer because after the edit it nicely explains how UDP works. Hope OP will accept it...

Comment: Thank you then. I just wanted to cut the usless talking, pardon if I was aggressive.